# Cache fsockopen result?

Tags: php, fsockopen

Is it possible to cahce the result of fsockopen for, lets say, 5 minutes?
This i need because of the slow website loading, i went from 0.00001s page load to 1.00137s page load time with fsockopen (this is when the server does not respond.

CODE:

```
<?php $fp = @fsockopen('127.0.0.1', '666');
if ($fp) { echo 'online'; }else{ echo 'offline'; }?>
```

Comment: Sure is this possible, but what is your problem with that?

Comment: You are going to need to show us the code you're having trouble with so we can give you appropriate advice.  There are a few different ways to interpret your question, and any answer other than "yes that is possible" is going to be difficult without knowing more.